Downloading multiple blobs asynchronously - Azure Function - check for running loop
In a [previous question][1], I asked how to download data asynchronously, which was answered. However, when running the code on an Azure Function, I get the following error asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop when running multiple invocations of the Azure Function, in which case I would think they are being run on the same thread. I understand you can check for a running event loop, but I'd appreciate advice on where best, and how to incorporate it into the code below.
from azure.storage.blob.aio import BlobServiceClient

async def download_blob_to_file(blob_service_client: BlobServiceClient, container_name, transaction_date, customer_id):
    blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=f"{transaction_date}/{customer_id}.csv")
    with open(file=f'{customer_id}.csv', mode="wb") as sample_blob:
        download_stream = await blob_client.download_blob()
        data = await download_stream.readall()
        sample_blob.write(data)


async def main(transaction_date, customer_id):
    connect_str = "connection-string"
    blob_serv_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)

    async with blob_serv_client as blob_service_client:
        await download_blob_to_file(blob_service_client, "sample-container", transaction_date, customer_id)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    transaction_date = '20240409'
    customer_id = '001'
    # customer_id_list = ['001', '002', '003', '004']
    asyncio.run(main(transaction_date, customer_id))```


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78377808/download-multiple-azure-blobs-asynchronously


In which trigger function are you trying?

I downloaded the blob files using the HTTP trigger function, see this output in local and browser.

So the initial code (the answer in the previous question) worked fine on its own (HTTP trigger), but if multiple calls were made to the function at the same time, it returned the "asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop". Can you explain how your revised code addresses this? I see this code matches very closely with the code from the previous answer with the omission of asyncio.run.

As per your code, it's throwing an error because the asyncio.run() has a similar job as HTTP trigger.

I successfully downloaded the CSV blob files using the HTTP trigger function in the Python V1 model.
Code :
init.py :
import azure.functions as func
from azure.storage.blob.aio import BlobServiceClient
import asyncio
import os

async def download_blob_to_file(blob_service_client: BlobServiceClient, container_name, transaction_date, customer_id):
    blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=f"{transaction_date}/{customer_id}.csv")
    async with blob_client:
        data = await blob_client.download_blob()
        content = await data.readall()
        with open(f'{customer_id}.csv', mode="wb") as file:
            file.write(content)

async def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    transaction_date = req.params.get('transaction_date')
    customer_ids_param = req.params.get('customer_ids')

    if transaction_date is None or customer_ids_param is None:
        return func.HttpResponse("Missing parameters", status_code=400)

    customer_id_list = customer_ids_param.split(',')

    connect_str = os.environ["Connect_str"]
    blob_serv_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)

    async with blob_serv_client:
        tasks = []
        for customer_id in customer_id_list:
            task = asyncio.create_task(download_blob_to_file(blob_serv_client, "sample-container", transaction_date, customer_id))
            tasks.append(task)
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

    return func.HttpResponse("Blob download completed.", status_code=200)

local.settings.json :
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "<storage_conne>",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "Connect_str": "<storage_conne>"
  }
}

Output :
The blob files were successfully downloaded using the above HTTP trigger function, as shown below:



Browser output :
http://localhost:7071/api/HttpTrigger1?transaction_date=20240409&customer_ids=001,002,003,004

Blob download completed.


The above code works locally for downloading blob files; however, in the Azure Portal, we should store the downloaded files in a temp directory because the Python function runs only on Linux. Consequently, I added the lines below for the temp directory before deploying the project to the Azure Function App.
import tempfile

        with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as temp_dir:
            file_path = os.path.join(temp_dir, f"{customer_id}.csv")
            with open(file_path, mode="wb") as file:

Deployment to Azure Function App :

Azure Portal :


